# If Else in Djnago Views

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm making a ***LMS***. 
Where a User applies for a leave and the admin accepts or rejects it.
Right now I am stuck in a problem where I want the user to apply for a leave through the Django form by selecting a leave type (casual, sick, half pay etc), if the admin accepts it then the default values in the database changes or gets deducted from the Employee model and when the counter reaches 0 an error is generated that you don't have any leaves,contact the admin.

I'm unable to understand how to make the logic for it.

I tried Applying if else statement in the views and even in the models.

***views.py***

```py
The function name is "Reject" as I am trying to make changes to the accept function.



def reject_leave(request, id): 
    # employee_item = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
    all_item = Leave.objects.get(id=id)
    all = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'all': all,'all_item': all_item}

'''
if the leave_type (choice field of the leaves from the django form) equals to a leave type like Annual leave 

The the program deducts 1 or the amount entered from the total value of Annual leave from the Model Employee
'''

*Sorry for the poor writing I'm not experienced in Django*


***This code is saying that in an illogical way.***

 if leave_type.id is "Annual_leave":
                Annual_leave - 1
    else:
                subject = "Leave Rejected"  # email subject
                email_from = "settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER"  # email from
                to_email = ['someemail@something.com']  # email to

                with open(...) as f:
                    msgbody = f.read()
                    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                    subject=subject, body=msgbody, from_email=email_from, to=to_email)
                    html_template = get_template(...).render()
                    msg.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
                    msg.send()

    return render(request, 'projectfiles/rejectemail.html',context)
```

***forms.py***

```py
class Leave_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    to_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%y'),
                               attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                      'placeholder': ' Month/Date/Year'}))


    from_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%y'),
                               attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                               'placeholder':' Month/Date/Year'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Leave
        fields = ['leave_Type', 'description',
                  'from_date', 'to_date', 'leave_qty']
        exclude = ['employee_leaves', 'submit_date']
        leave_type_choice = (

            ("Annual_leave", "Annual leave"),
            ("Sick_leave", "Sick leave"),
            ("Casual_leave", "Casual leave"),
            ("Emergency_leave", "Emergency leave"),
            ("Half_pay","Half Pay")
    )

        widgets = {


            'leave_Type': forms.Select(choices = leave_type_choice, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Enter description here', 'rows': 3, 'cols': 21})}
```

***models.py***

```py
class Employee(models.Model):

    employee_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    employee_designation = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    employee_department = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    Annual_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=10)
    Sick_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=3)
    Casual_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=3)
    Half_pay = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=4)
    Emergency_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=3)
    allowed = models.BooleanField(default=False)



    def __str__(self):
                return self.employee_name.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Employee"





class Leave(models.Model):

    employee_leaves = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_Type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    leave_qty = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    from_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    to_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)



    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Leave"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.leave_Type + "  by  " + str(self.employee_leaves)
```

When the Admin accepts (or in this case rejects) a leave. 
e.g. 
Sick leave I want 1 or entered amount of leaves to be deducted from the total of the allocated sick leaves.

Comment: `if leave_type.id is "Annual_leave":`? leave_type appears to be undefined.  Also `Annual_leave - 1` is not a real assignment

Comment: yes, its undefined even if I pass it as usual. I want it to fetch the defaults from the ***Employee*** model and compare if there are any leaves left. I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def reject_leave(request, id):  # overwriting built-in id is not a good idea
    all_item = Leave.objects.get(id=id)  # This is a single item, not all items
    all = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  # this again is a single item, not all items
    context = {'all': all, 'all_item': all_item}

    if leave_type.id is "Annual_leave":
    # What is leave_type?
        Annual_leave - 1 
        # What is Annual_leave? What does -1 supposed to do? 
    # Maybe you meant 
    # employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
    # leave = employee.employee_leaves_set.last() 
    # if leave.leave_Type == 'Annual_leave':
    #     employee.Annual_leave -= 1
    #     employee.save()
    else:
        subject = "Leave Rejected"
        email_from = "settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER"
        to_email = ['talhamurtaza@clickmail.info']

        with open('...') as f:
            msgbody = f.read()
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                subject=subject, body=msgbody, from_email=email_from, to=to_email)
            html_template = get_template(
                "...").render()
            msg.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
            msg.send()

    return render(request, 'projectfiles/rejectemail.html', context)
```

There is so many things wrong with this that I can confidently say you haven't taken a python tutorial, read pep-8 nor taken a django tutorial. So please start from the first one and work your way up.

Comment: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'employee_leaves_set'

Comment: My bad, `employee.leave_set.last()`

Comment: It's working ***THANK YOU***
and 
Please explain to me what I did wrong and how can I improve my logic.

Comment: I tried to explain it in the python comments in the code snippet, idk if I can explain it any further, but glad I could help. Also, *coughs* [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)

Comment: But now I'm getting this.

AttributeError at /rejectmail/2/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'leave_Type'

Comment: That means that employee has no leaves